# Swift string array does not save the data when .append called

Tags: swift

Hi I have an array of String = ["one","two","three"]

the data 1,2,3 is already in the array, I want to append new data to the array, the append works and the fourth object is appended, YET after exiting the view and coming back its gone again, witch means it doesn't save it ,
after a long search in google nothing came up.
what to I do about it? 
and if NSUserdefaults String array is the only solution?

```
var HouseArray :[String] = []
let CarArray :[String] = []
let PartyArray :[String] = []
let StudyArray :[String] = []
var FavoArray :[String] = []
let InsureArray :[String] = []
let ShoppingArray :[String] =  []
let CreditArray :[String] = []
let KidsArray :[String] = []

let SaveArray : [String] = []
let SaveData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var ImageIs = "House"
var imgIndicator:Int = 0
var newStringIs:String!
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //GetTodaysMonthAndYear()
    WitchImageSelected()
    tableView.reloadData()


}

func WitchImageSelected(){

    ImageIs = SaveData.valueForKey("Image") as! String!

    switch(ImageIs){
    case "House":
        imgIndicator = 0

    case "Car":
        imgIndicator = 1
    case "Party":
        imgIndicator = 2
    case "Cart":
        imgIndicator = 3
    case "CreditCard":
        imgIndicator = 4
    case "Study":
        imgIndicator = 5
    case "Insure":
        imgIndicator = 6
    case "Favo":
        imgIndicator = 7
    case "Kids":
        imgIndicator = 8
    default: break
    }

    if(SaveData.valueForKey("newString") != nil){
        newStringIs = SaveData.valueForKey("newString") as! String!
        SaveData.setValue(nil, forKey: "newString")

  HouseArray.append(newStringIs)

    }
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let Index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    if segue.identifier == "EnterPrice"{
        switch(imgIndicator){
        case 0: SaveData.setValue("\(HouseArray[Index!.row])", forKey: "NameLabel")
        case 1: SaveData.setValue("\(CarArray[Index!.row])", forKey: "NameLabel")
        case 2: SaveData.setValue("\(PartyArray[Index!.row])", forKey: "NameLabel")
        case 3: SaveData.setValue("\(ShoppingArray[Index!.row])", forKey: "NameLabel")
        case 4: SaveData.setValue("\(CreditArray[Index!.row])", forKey: "NameLabel")
        case 5: SaveData.setValue("\(StudyArray[Index!.row])", forKey: "NameLabel")
        case 6: SaveData.setValue("\(InsureArray[Index!.row])", forKey: "NameLabel")
        case 7: SaveData.setValue("\(FavoArray[Index!.row])", forKey: "NameLabel")
        case 8: SaveData.setValue("\(KidsArray[Index!.row])", forKey: "NameLabel")

        default: break
        }




}
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    switch(imgIndicator){
    case 0: return HouseArray.count
    case 1: return CarArray.count
    case 2: return PartyArray.count
    case 3: return ShoppingArray.count
    case 4: return CreditArray.count
    case 5: return StudyArray.count
    case 6: return InsureArray.count
    case 7: return FavoArray.count
    case 8: return KidsArray.count

    default: return 0
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let SlideOutCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SlideCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    switch(imgIndicator){
    case 0: SlideOutCell.textLabel?.text = HouseArray[indexPath.row]
    case 1: SlideOutCell.textLabel?.text = CarArray[indexPath.row]
    case 2: SlideOutCell.textLabel?.text = PartyArray[indexPath.row]
    case 3: SlideOutCell.textLabel?.text = ShoppingArray[indexPath.row]
    case 4: SlideOutCell.textLabel?.text = CreditArray[indexPath.row]
    case 5: SlideOutCell.textLabel?.text = StudyArray[indexPath.row]
    case 6: SlideOutCell.textLabel?.text = InsureArray[indexPath.row]
    case 7: SlideOutCell.textLabel?.text = FavoArray[indexPath.row]
    case 8: SlideOutCell.textLabel?.text = KidsArray[indexPath.row]

    default: break
    }



    return SlideOutCell
}
```

}

Comment: If you don't save whatever you append to the array before it is deallocated, and you re-initialize the array to ` ["one","two","three"]` when your object is allocated, what would you expect to happen?  Where could the data possibly be saved?

Comment: Please update your example with some code. It is likely that when you exit the view, it is being deallocated so whatever data you have added will not persist.

Comment: i add the code , and you both right , now i do i save it before it deallocate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your view disappears, the `ViewController` object is deallocated from the memory, which means that everything inside it, is lost. You have almost no way of finding the lost data back.

:(

That's why you need to save the data somewhere before the vc is deallocated. You can either save it in CoreData, or in `NSUserDefaults`. And I recommend the former.

`NSUserDefaults` is supposed to be used to save user preferences/settings, so it is not suitable to save the data in your case to `NSUserDefaults`. Especially when the array gets larger and larger.

To save data in CoreData, here is roughly what you need to do:

- create a core data data model
- design your entities. I think this would be very simple, just add an entity and add a property called `string` to it.
- generate a `NSManagedObject` subclass
- get the managed object context and you can start querying the "database", although it is just an object model

To learn more, see this tutotial:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but can you explain where does the array allocated ? i mean if i append to a strong property why doesn't it allocate and save the extra object auto?

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick. @A.Pinhasov